# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while write to a Apache POI workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` while writing in to an **POI workbook** of File output stream.

Below is the Code:

```
public void generate(String outFileName) throws Exception
  {
OutputStream fileOut = null;
File file = new File(outFileName);
if(!file.exists()) {
   file.createNewFile();
}
fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

String templateFileNameWithDir = "doc/IntradoTvwGenerateTemplate.xls";

Workbook inWorkbook = getWorkbook(templateFileNameWithDir);
Workbook outWorkbook = copyWorkbook(outFileName, inWorkbook);
int currentRow = 0;
currentRow = addRowsNew(fileOut, outWorkbook, inWorkbook.getSheetAt(0));

      outWorkbook.write(fileOut);
      outWorkbook.close();
      inWorkbook.close();
      fileOut.flush();
      fileOut.close();
}

public Workbook getWorkbook(String templateFileNameWithDir) throws Exception
  {
    InputStream ios = null;
    Workbook inWorkBook = null;
    try{
        File inputFile = new File(templateFileNameWithDir);
        ios = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        inWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(ios);
    }
    finally {
        ios.close();
    }
    return inWorkBook;
  }

public Workbook copyWorkbook(String outFileName, Workbook inWorkbook) throws Exception
  {
    Workbook outWorkbook = inWorkbook;
    return outWorkbook;
  }
```

And I'm getting NullPointer at this line of **generate()** method,-

```
outWorkbook.write(fileOut);
```

The exception log is like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode$FilteringIterator.<init>(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:193)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode$FilteringIterator.<init>(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:188)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode.getEntries(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:101)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode.iterator(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:105)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.EntryUtils.copyNodes(EntryUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.EntryUtils.copyNodes(EntryUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1465)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1439)
    at com.sprint.neo.e911.util.SpreadSheetIteratorHelper.generate(SpreadSheetIteratorHelper.java:495)
at com.sprint.neo.e911.util.tvw.TVWSpreadSheetGenerator.generateIntradoTVWSpreadSheet(TVWSpreadSheetGenerator.java:96)
```

Please help me to get through this error. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** adding **addRowsNew()** method

```
public int addRowsNew(OutputStream out, Workbook wb, Sheet sourceSheet){

int currentRow=0;
Sheet outSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
CellStyle cellStyle = null;
Row row = sourceSheet.getRow(rowStart);
cellStyle = row.getCell(i).getCellStyle();

Row rowOut = outSheet.createRow((short)currentRow);
Cell cell = rowOut.createCell(2);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
cell.setCellValue(value.toString());

currentRow++;
return currentRow;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: What does `copyWorkbook()` do? Could it return `null`?

Comment: Yes I debugged the code. Its that particular line I mentioned, where the null-pointer is throwing.

Comment: `copyWorkbook()` basically copies **inputWorkbook** into an **outputWorkbook** object and returns.

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? Does it work if you comment out `//currentRow = addRowsNew(fileOut, outWorkbook, inWorkbook.getSheetAt(0));`? If so, the `addRowsNew` is the problem. Then please show the code of that method.

Comment: I'm using apache **POI - 3.16** version. I edited the `addRowsNew()` method. Please check.

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproducing that issue without having [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For me there is no logik behind your `addRowsNew` method. Why the `OutputStream out` as a parameter? It is not used then. Why always setting `currentRow` `0`?  Where is `rowStart` coming from? What is `i`? ...? ...?